# Database design - composite key relationship issue

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key-relationship, composite-key

I had posted a similar question before, but this is more specific.  Please have a look at the following diagram:
[image: DatabaseTableDesignIssue]
The explanation of this design is as follows:

- Bakers produce many Products
- The same Product can be produced by more than one Baker
- Bakers change their pricing from time-to-time for certain (of their) Products
- Orders can be created, but not necessarily finalised

The aim here is to allow the store manager to create an Order "Basket" based on whatever goods are required, and also allow the system being created to determine the best price at that time based on what Products are contained within the Order.

I therefore envisaged the `ProductOrders` table to initially hold the `productID` and associated `orderID`, whilst maintaining a null (undetermined) value for `bakerID` and `pricingDate`, as that would be determined and updated by the system, which would *then* constitute a finalised order.

Now that you have an idea of what I am trying to do, please advise me on how to to best set these relationships up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, an unfinalised order is not yet assigned a baker / pricing (meaning when an order is placed, no baker has yet been selected to bake the product).

In which case, the order is probably placed against the Products Table and then "Finalized" against the BakersProducts table.

A solution could be to give ProductsOrders 2 separate "ProductID's", one being for the original ordered ProductId (i.e. Non Nullable) - say ProductId, and the second being part of the Foreign key to the assigned BakersProducts (say ProductId2). Meaning that in ProductsOrders, the composite foreign keys BakerId, ProductId2 and PricingDate are all nullable, as they will only be set once the order is Finalized.

In order to remove this redundancy, what you might also consider is using surrogate keys instead of the composite keys. This way BakersProducts would have a surrogate PK (e.g. BakersProductId) which would then be referenced as a nullable FK in ProductsOrders. This would also avoid the confusion with the Direct FK in ProductsOrders to Product.ProductId (which from above, was the original Product line as part of the Order).

HTH?

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BakersProducts
(
  BakerProductId int identity(1,1) not null, -- New Surrogate PK here
  BakerId int not null,
  ProductId int not null,
  PricingDate datetime not null,
  Price money not null,
  StockLevel bigint not null,

  CONSTRAINT PK_BakerProducts PRIMARY KEY(BakerProductId),
  CONSTRAINT FK_BakerProductsProducts FOREIGN KEY(ProductId) REFERENCES dbo.Products(ProductId),
  CONSTRAINT FK_BakerProductsBaker FOREIGN KEY(BakerId) REFERENCES dbo.Bakers(BakerId),
  CONSTRAINT U_BakerProductsPrice UNIQUE(BakerId, ProductId, PricingDate) -- Unique Constraint mimicks the original PK for uniqueness ... could also use a unique index
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductOrders
(
  OrderId INT NOT NULL,
  ProductId INT NOT NULL, -- This is the original Ordered Product set when order is created
  BakerProductId INT NULL, -- This is nullable and gets set when Order is finalised with a baker
  OrderQuantity BIGINT NOT NULL,


  CONSTRAINT FK_ProductsOrdersBakersProducts FOREIGN KEY(BakersProductId) REFERENCES dbo.BakersProducts(BakerProductId)
  .. Other Keys here
)
```

Comment: @nonnb: yes, you are correct with your initial understanding. Your suggestion of `Products.productID`->`ProductOrders.productID` sounds better, as I was trying to kill 2 birds stone so to speak by trying to reference only one table which already had `productID`. nonnb, if I create a surrogate key on `BakersProducts` and reference that instead, is that not still considered redundant design? Also, is there a difference between a Primary Key and a Surrogate Key? thank you!

Comment: sorry, with my question about it still being considered redundant design, I'm considering what you are saying about the redundancy, but seeing `BakersProductId' as a key in a table that already contains `productID'. So from my perspective, it appears as though `ProductOrders` still has 2 `productID`s in a way. Or am I understanding redundancy wrong, and you mean that each row should not contain duplicate values?  If I go with your suggestion, I will have to manage the relationship carefully on my application-end.

Comment: so ideally, in `BakersProducts`, `productID` & `bakerID` should be non-nullable foreign-keys against their respective tables, but should **not** be part of a composite key, and also have a surrogate key in `BakersProducts`

Comment: Apols - by "redundant" I wasn't trying to allude to some kind of perfect design, but more from a maintainability point of view - composite keys often can cause confusion, and it becomes tempting to short circuit joins. You are right, even when replacing the 3 x composite keys with a single surrogate there are inherently still 2 "ProductIds". However, trying to roll up a single ProductId just seems wrong (since the Foreign Key on ProductsOrders "Moves" from the Products table (before finalization) to the BakersProducts table once the baker has been selected.

Comment: is this better? [http://i.imgur.com/ZmXSP.gif](http://i.imgur.com/ZmXSP.gif) sqlserver management studio designer didn't seem to thro any errors with this

Comment: thx for the feedback. I guess its fine though...when I (from the application POV) am updating `ProductOrders` for finalization, I'll do something to the effect of `select priceID from BakersProducts BP where BP.productID = [productID in ProductOrders table]`.    `BakersProducts` is more a sort of pricelist, so makes more sense (semantically) to call the surrogate key `priceID`.

Comment: ah, I only saw your sql script now. I understand it better now when I saw the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT. thanx nonnb for your help!

Comment: Re : Updated ERD - thats pretty much it, although the PriceId FK on ProductsOrders will need to be NULLABLE as it won't be set until you finalise your order, unless you use a "magic value" pattern (e.g. inserting a dummy ProductOrders record e.g. 0 to satisfy the FK). This would be updated when the order is finalised

Comment: oops, forgot abot that! But excellent stuff! Thanx for your time and patience nonnb!

Comment: @nonnb : one last question (promise!) - `ProductOrders` is meant to be an association table. Should I not make `ProductOrders.orderID` and `ProductOrders.productID` primary keys? Abidng to the bsuiness rules, those 2 values will uniquely identify a single row, and the table could be considered as normalised?

Comment: nevermind, come to think about it, those 2 columns should be made primary keys, as I'll need to refer to them when updating/deleting. Also, EntityFramework will start complaining if there's no primary key on the the table and will assume it as read-only.

Comment: Yes, you can make those 2 a PK if the business consequences are intended (meaning that the same product can't be added twice to the same order etc, but it would also mean that the whole ProductOrder line can only be outsourced to one baker). If you do need multiple ProducOrders then I would suggest another surrogate key!